# Using two keyboards within a Game

Tags: python, game-engine

I am making a game where the screen is split into two, so that two players can play on the same screen.

For this, i want both players to control their players in the same way.

Is it possible to differentiate between two keyboards, so that Keyboard 1 controls motion of Player 1, and Keyboard 2 controls motion of Player 2?

Comment: The short answer is No, however you can use multiple joysticks to control different players by assigning a frequency for the joystick sensor.

Comment: use wasd for one and arrows for another.

Comment: well that sucks, cause i wanted to do like two player ps3, but for computer with keyboards :(